# How can I use accessibilityScrollAction in SwiftUI?

Tags: scroll, accessibility, action, swiftui, xcode11

How can I use accessibilityScrollAction? Can I deactivate the swipe function in a form or list?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Vorschau: View {
     @State var pickOn = 0
     @State var PickedName : String = ""
     var body: some View {
          Form{
               Picker("MaPicker", selection: $pickOn) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 5) { x in
                         Text("\(x)").tag(x)
                    }
               }.accessibilityScrollAction(<#T##handler: (Edge) -> Void##(Edge) -> Void#>)
          }
     }
}
     #if DEBUG
     struct Vorschau_Previews: PreviewProvider {
          static var previews: some View {
               Vorschau()
          }
     }
#endif
```